# Editor placeholder in source file with print values

Tags: xcode, editor, placeholder

I keep running into "editor placeholder in source file" error with my print snapshot values after the update. If I try to delete the line of code, the app crashes.

```
 let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("docs")//.child(UID!)
    reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value ?? <#default value#>)
        }, withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<#default value#>` in your `print` statement with some actual default value.

The `<#` and `#>` denote an editor placeholder, as commonly used in Xcode snippets. If Xcode sees those characters in a source file, it turns them into a bubble that you can select by pressing `Tab` and then replace just by typing. Xcode creates a warning when it finds these editor placeholders (which your settings may be escalating to an error) to call your attention to the fact that there is some code missing.

For example, inside any Swift function, type `docatch` and hit Enter. Xcode fills in [a do-catch snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3q1e.png). The second line is really just `try <#throwing expression#>`, but Xcode makes it look fancy.